How to pass list of LICN_CIVIL_ID that have checkbox checked true separated comma using java script?
I work on java script i display data on grid view using JavaScript and it display success on grid view gvResults using function  GET_WORLD_BANK_LICN_DATA_REP()
so data display success on grid view gvResults  using function below without any issue
my issue how to pass list of selected P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].LICN_CIVIL_ID that have checkbox checked true from grid view to button
as separated comma to function getselected_civilid when press button btnRequestSearch
so suppose I display data and select checkbox checked  for P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].LICN_CIVIL_ID as 1245,4321,7891,9918
then it will passed to function getselected_civilid() as "1245","4321","7891","9918" when press button below :
<button type="button" id="btnRequestSearch" class="btn btn-outline-primary col-12" onclick="getselected_civilid();return false;">
                            <span style="font-size: 28px;">print</span><i class="far fa-hand-point-up fa-fw fa-2x pull-center"></i>
                        </button>
function getselected_civilid()
{
}

AND code below executed when display data on grid view using java script
function GET_WORLD_BANK_LICN_DATA_REP() {
  debugger
  var P_ACT_ID_LIST = $('#ddl_activities').val();
  var P_LICN_COUNT = $('#txtcountlicense').val();
  var P_EXPIRY_YEAR = $('#txt_year').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "../BusinessLayer/WebMethods.asmx/GET_WORLD_BANK_LICN_DATA_REP",
    data: "{'P_ACT_ID_LIST':'" + P_ACT_ID_LIST + "','P_LICN_COUNT':'" + P_LICN_COUNT + "','P_EXPIRY_YEAR':'" + P_EXPIRY_YEAR + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("STicket", MYLIBRARY.ReturnTicket());

      $("#gvResults").empty();
    },
    success: function(Result) {
      CloseLoading();

      $.each(Result.d, function(key, value) {
        if (value.Status == "1") {
          if (value.P_LICNS_CURInfo != null) {
            if (value.P_LICNS_CURInfo.length > 0) {
              var rowNo = 0;
              for (var i in value.P_LICNS_CURInfo) {
                var row = "<tr align='center' id='tr" + (rowNo + 1) + "' class='record'> " + "<td class='tdCount'>" +
                  (rowNo + 1) + "</td><td>" +
                  value.P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].comm_book_no + "</td> <td>" +
                  value.P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].LICN_COMM_NO + "</td> <td>" +
                  value.P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].LICN_CIVIL_ID + "</td> <td>" +
                  value.P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].LEGAL_STRACTURE_DESC + "</td> <td>" +
                  value.P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].ADDRESS_GOV_DESC + "</td> <td>" +
                  value.P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].MAIL + "</td>" +
                  "<td><input type='checkbox' name='statusCheckbox' value='" + value.P_LICNS_CURInfo[i].LICN_CIVIL_ID + "' /></td></tr>";

                row = $(row).hide();
                $('#gvResults').append($(row));
                rowNo++;
                $(row).fadeIn(1000);
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          ModelSuccessDanger('???? !!', value.StatusDesc, '0', null);
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(msg, status) {
      CloseLoading();
      if (status === "error") {
        var errorMessage = $.parseJSON(msg.responseText);
      
      }
    }
  });
}

How to get LICN_CIVIL_ID that have checkbox checked true separated comma when press button pass LICN_CIVIL_ID separated comma
1934,4332,8991,8881 to function getselected_civilid() using JavaScript

Put them in an array and use array.join(',') to turn it into a comma-separated string.

can you show me exactly how to do it full code i'm not familiar with javascript

Why don't you put LICN_CIVIL_ID in the value of the checkbox, instead of SomeValue? That would make it easier to get those values from the selected checkboxes.

i modified my original post from somevalue to LICN_CIVIL_ID so how to pass list of LICN_CIVIL_ID  from gridivew to function getselected_civilid() when click button

Use .map() to loop over all the selected checkboxes, return their values, and join them into a string.


function getselected_civilid()
{
  const selected_cbs = $(":checkbox[name='statusCheckbox']:checked");
  const civil_ids = selected_cbs.map((i, cb) => cb.value).get().join(",");
  // do something with civil_ids
}




ok are there are any changes on function GET_WORLD_BANK_LICN_DATA_REP() because you use .record are this class or what

Refresh, I got rid of that when you changed the value.

last question no need to determine name of grid view  gvResults before $(":checkbox[name='statusCheckbox']:checked")

If you have statusCheckbox in other grids then you could use a more specific selector, like $("#gvResults :checkbox[name'statusCheckbox']:checked")
